# Unable to locate package `docker-ce` on a Ubuntu Cloud 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker, cloud

I'm trying to install Docker on a Ubuntu Cloud 18.04 LTS following official installation docs. On another Ubuntu 18.04 installation everything works fine, but it is a Ubuntu Workstaion 18.04. On a cloud version I've got error "Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate" after executing sudo apt-get install docker-ce. Repository recommended by documentation is installed. Any idea what should I do?

Some details:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  docker-ce-cli:amd64

uname -a
Linux ubuntu02 4.15.0-65-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 17 17:12:56 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thanks for showing interest.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the full error output of your command?

Comment: Weclcome, could you add the output of `uname -a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install `docker-ce` you should have the **64-bit** version of Ubuntu Cloud ([ubuntu cloud image 18.04](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/release/)).

> [OS requirements](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#os-requirements)
>
> To install Docker Engine - Community, you need the 64-bit version of one of these Ubuntu versions:
>
> Disco 19.04
>
> Cosmic 18.10
>
> Bionic 18.04 (LTS)
>
> Xenial 16.04 (LTS)
>
> Docker Engine - Community is supported on x86_64 (or amd64), armhf, arm64, s390x (IBM Z), and ppc64le (IBM Power) architectures.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu 18.04 package for the Docker container runtime is `docker.io`.  You would run `apt-get install docker.io` to install it from the default Ubuntu repositories.

The `docker-ce` package comes from Docker, not from Ubuntu.  You would have to [configure their repository](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) to get that package.